# Have a list of files, move them using one command

Tags: linux, terminal, shell

I have run a command which finds a lot of files based on some search criteria. It returns the files like so:

```
./somepath/somepath/file.something
./asdf/asdf/s.php
./etc/a.php
./a/b/c/d/e/f/g.jpg
```

So I was wondering, if I capture this output into a file (ie. one file per line), can anyone help me write a command which iterates through the file and moves the files one by one to a specified directory?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while read -r filename
  do
  mv -- "$filename" directory
done < list_of_files.txt
```

Not tested (I'm on a work PC running Windows) but should work.

Comment: The basic approach is sound, but your original version was missing several protections against “unusual” filenames. Always use `read -r`, as plain `read` expands some backslashes. **Always use double quotes around variable substitutions** unless you know *why not to*; without the quotes, the shell would expand whitespace and `\[?*` in file names. Finally, `--` before the file names on the `mv` command line protects a file name beginning with a `-` from being considered an option by the `mv` command.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  Dashed it off without proper care--thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks! I also gave it a try myself and ended up with a 30 line php script.

Answer (score 2):

```
your_command | xargs -I% mv "%" dest_dir
```

If your command is `find` or you have some way of terminating the filenames with a null:

```
your_command | xargs -0 -I% mv "%" dest_dir
```

or

```
find [find-args] -print0 | xargs -0 -I% mv "%" dest_dir
```

Using nulls to terminate filenames allows this to work with filenames that may contain spaces, newlines, etc.

You can also use `xargs` to process your file if you've already created it:

```
xargs -a filename -I% mv "%" dest_dir
```

Comment: Why are you giving instructions on removing the files when he wants to move them?

Comment: I'm betting Dennis copied that from an example and didn't customize it.

Comment: No, I didn't copy it. I take full credit for the foul-up. I will correct my examples.

Comment: @mqchen: Note the `-I%` in Dennis's answer. This is important: without it, `xargs` expects input quoted in a peculiar way and would fail if your file names contain characters such as whitespace and `\'"`.

Answer (score -1):

Another option, if the filenames don't contain any whitespace, would be

```
mv `search_command_here` dest_directory
```

(The backtick syntax is also a bash-ism, but the question specifically states that this is on Linux and all major Linux distros use bash by default.)

Comment: The backtick syntax may be a Linux/Unix-ism, but it's not a Bashism. Every major shell uses it. Even the preferred `$()` syntax is not a Bashism as it's available in most modern shells and is specified by POSIX.

Comment: Not only whitespace, but also wildcards (`*?[`) and backslashes in file names will be expanded by the shell with this command.